# Getting webpage source code with java

Tags: java, android, instagram, feed

I'm trying to get a webpage source code with JAVA but i fail all the time! I want to get the source code from the link below.

http://widget.websta.me/rss/n/wikirap_official

I searched on the net and tried many codes but all returned nothing, this page return my INSTAGRAM user posts as feed.

**please test codes on this link and if you succeeded in get source, share the code with me.**

Comment: **please test codes on this link and if you succeeded in get source, share the code with me.**. Really? Write a code, test it and if successful share the code. Why don't you hire me?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 huh, You guys think that ur android developer so must paid anytime for anything and only working for money...
im sorry for you and guys who voted down.. 
it was just a request, but looks like sb is in need of money

Comment: Oh yeah right. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about `Android` but this is how you can read web page source in Java.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;

public class readURL  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String generate_URL = "http://www.example.com";
        String inputLine;
        try {
            URL data = new URL(generate_URL);
            /**
             * Proxy code start 
             * If you are working behind firewall uncomment below lines. 
             * Set your proxy server
             */

            /* Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.202", 8080)); */
            /* HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) data.openConnection(proxy); */

            /* Proxy code end */

            /* Open connection */
            /* comment below line in case of Proxy */
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) data.openConnection(); 
            /* Read webpage coontent */
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            /* Read line by line */
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            /* close BufferedReader */
            in.close();
            /* close HttpURLConnection */
            con.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```